# Simple jQuery image slider with centralized slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, slide

I have an HTML like below;

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="slidea"><img src="slidea.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li class="slideb"><img src="slideb.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li class="slidec"><img src="slidec.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
<a href="#" id="next">next</a>
```

and CSS like this;

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.slider{
  height: 100px;
  background: #9966CC;
  text-align: center;
}
wrapper{
  width: 100px;
}
.slides{
  list-style: none;
}
.slideb,.slidec{
  display: none;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a simple image slider. There are 3 images (may be more) and they are in a list. Images other the than first one are set to `display: none;`. I want second image to `fadeIn` after 3 secs, and third again after 3 secs, so the interval of slideshow is 3 secs.

I tried this;

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slideb').fadeIn();
}, 3000);
```

How can I make what I am trying to? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c55k946j/).

Comment: Do you want to avoid a third-party solution? Because otherwise, I might checkout cycle.js. It's pretty lightweight, but still powerful.

Comment: @JakeParis no problem with 3rd party..

Comment: Give http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ a lookat. It's pretty easy to work with.

Comment: can the images be centralized?

Comment: Yes, but see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center an image using cycle2.js (see the comment string on the question), you can use the following after the slideshow is initialized.

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-before',function(e,opts){

        // move the slides to the center of the box

        $('.cycle-slide').each(function() {

            centerImage($(this));

        });

    });
```

And then create the centerImage function, but put it outside of main jquery load function so it can be accessed by the slideshow init event

```
function centerImage(el) {
    var w = el.width();
    var o = jQuery('.gallery').width();

    if (o > w) {
        var d = o-w;
        if (d>1) {
            l = d/2;
            el.css('margin-left',l);
        } else
            el.css('margin-left','0');

    } else
        el.css('margin-left','0');
}
```

Lastly, the following fires the centering for the first list. Also put this outside the main jquery load function otherwise it will fire too late

```
jQuery('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-post-initialize',function(){

    var slide1 = jQuery('.cycle-slide').eq(0);
    slide1.width( slide1.data('iwidth') + 'px');

    centerImage( slide1 );

});
```

Comment: lemme give it a try.. :)